# In Google Talk, how to send a message to person that is not in my friend list?

Tags: xmpp, google-contacts-api, google-talk

In [Google Talk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Talk), how to send a message to person that is not in my friend list?

I work on an application that notify customers of a bank about change of their accounts. When I send a message to a person not in my list, no error is created, but the message isn't delivered to the recipient.

Because of design issues it is not suitable to send an invitation to customers and store information about their responses to it.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking: "How do I send spam to people that don't want it?".  Perhaps you'd like to rephrase the question?

Comment: When I was typing question, I realized the note that the feature I need can be used for spamming. But my app can't store info of invitation state of every customer.

Answer (score 1):

You can message a user directly using XMPP without an active presence subscription (the requirement for an item to appear in your roster), but most clients (Google Talk clients included AFAIK) will discard the message upon reception, if the *from* header does not match a bare JID in their roster.

Comment: Against you, I think this is not a client-side issue for Google. I can receive message from non-friend@jabber.org by pidgin client but no message delivered from non-friend@gmail.com by same client. Probably it is an anti-spam server-side policy of Google.